# Relation between divisible R-module and Frac(R)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In the proof of the following lemma taken from Enochs's book: "Relative Homological Algebra", I don't figure out two things:

1) Why can $G$ be embedded  as a submodule of a torsion-free and divisible module $G'$?

2) Why is a torsion-free and divisible $R$-module necessarily isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $R$ is a domain. We call its fraction field $K$.

(1) If $G$ is a torsion-free $R$-module it embeds into $G\otimes_RK$, which is divisible.

(2) If $G$ is a torsion-free, divisible $R$-module then it is a vector space over $K$.